# What's the community's position on copyrighted material?

Tags: discussion, policy

Copyright was covered briefly in an answer to [a previous question](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100/what-kind-of-illustrations-support-questions-and-answers/101#101), but not really addressed.

The Stack Exchange [content policy document](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) is a bit vague on the subject:

> users should be careful when using copyrighted content without the
>   permission of those who created it

...so I wondered what this community thinks about it? I am noticing a few copyrighted illustrations in answers (mostly), and wanted to ask around before starting to deal with it.

Answer (score 10):

I'm a small-time open-access publisher, not a lawyer, but have done lots of research about this, and spoken to Creative Commons counsel about it. So I will make a proposal.

@Neo wrote [in the question I mentioned](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100/what-kind-of-illustrations-support-questions-and-answers/101#101):

> i dont think that is a copy right issue: journals are meant to be
>   cited, as long as they are cited. I do not need any permission to use
>   a diagram from a journal article in any form, if properly cited.

This is not quite right. It is a copyright issue, and you do need permission. Most journals (e.g. [GSA](http://www.geosociety.org/pubs/copyrt.htm)) have clearly stated terms of use, and often say something like "You can use one figure or short excerpts without permission." Others are rather strict (e.g. [AGU](http://publications.agu.org/author-resource-center/terms-of-use/)) and storage and digital reproduction are excluded entirely. You absolutely do need written permission for *any* use beyond the publisher's terms. Often this is handled through the [CCC](http://www.copyright.com/) (usually for a fee, sometimes quite large).

At least in some jurisdictions, we can make a [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) argument. This is a matter of judgment and I agree that SE probably qualifies in most cases, provided the excerpts are small and properly cited and labeled (see below).

There is also the issue of Stack Exchange's open license, [CC-BY-SA](http://bit.ly/cc-by-sa), which can in principle contain unlicensed material but probably shouldn't. Wikipedia, which uses the same license, has zero tolerance for it. There are exceptions, like a fair use claim for using a low-res cover image as a visual representation of a book, but even these are challenged all the time.

If a person really has to use unlicensed material, they should do three things:

1. Ensure that the use complies with the rights holder's terms.
2. Follow [the advice of  Creative Commons](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#May_I_apply_a_CC_license_to_my_work_if_it_incorporates_material_used_under_fair_use_or_another_exception_or_limitation_to_copyright.3F) and state explicitly that it is copyright and not licensed, name the rights holder, mention or link to any explicit or implicit permission they have for re-use (e.g. in the terms of use), and link to the source.
3. Cite the source with a full bibliographic citation and, preferably, [a DOI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier).

Notwithstanding all this, here's why I think we should strongly discourage the use of unlicensed copyrighted material:

- It would encourage the creation of more open access material, for example [to illustrate a point](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/2556/70).
- It would increase the impact of open work, like [Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Geology), [Figshare](http://figshare.com/articles/search?q=geology&figure=on&lsort=recent&ltype=tags&start=&end=), PLOS ONE, and so on.
- It would reduce the impact of non-open work.

I realize this probably all seems pedantic to most people, but I think most of us would agree that open access to scientific knowledge is important for society, and copyright abuse is rife in our field (just go to a conference and watch the parade of unlicensed material in people's talks). Instead of ignoring the issue, we can play a part in growing the amount of open material in geoscience.

Comment: Since stackexchange is US-based and hosted, "in some jurisdictions", in practice, can be replaced with "under US and International law"